# How to merge android 5 DatePicker with DataPicker lower APIs

Tags: android, android-activity, google-calendar-api

I'm use DatePickerDialog on Android Lollipop(method openCalendarLollipop) and for Calendar lower version I use second method.

I use second method for lower calendar, because if clicked cancel button dialog on eg. API 15 new date set, but it shouldn't without click “set”.

How I write one way?

I use Activity classes

**First method**

```
public void openCalendarLollipop(View v){
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new      
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) { }
    },y,m,d);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

**Second method**

```
public void openCalendar(View v){
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new 
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        }
    },y,m,d));
    datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis()+10000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28299001/3035416 you can refer this post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30844534/4447803 try this link

Comment: Proper code formatting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can simply use this Material Date Time Picker Library it works for me

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker