# Android create two DatePickers (without dialog) to enter "From" and "To" dates

Tags: android, datepicker

I' ve got two datepickers in my activity:

```
 DatePicker DatePickerDateStart = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datestart);
 DatePicker DatePickerDateEnd = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dateend);
```

I use spinner mode (datePickerMode) for both and the calendar (calendarViewShown) is hidden.

The 1st datepicker holds the *"From"* date and the 2nd the *"To"* date. I am trying to make the 2nd datepicker `setMinDate()` when the 1st datepicker changes value. So far I have this:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDateStart.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                Date mDate = sdf.parse(year + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + day);
                long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                DatePickerDateEnd.setMinDate(timeInMilliseconds);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

My issue is that `setMinDate()` works the 1st time the user selects a date from the *"From"* datepicker, but it doesn't set a min date after that (i.e. on a second change).

I noticed though, that it will `setMinDate()` again only if I change the year from the *"From"* datepicker. Then it sets a new min date again to the *"To"* datepicker. So I can get the desired behavior if I change the year firstly and then the rest of the spinners (day,month). But this is not right I guess, because the correct behavior will be to set a min date whenever a change is happening to any of the spinners (month,day,year). However `timeInMilliseconds` holds the new date on every change but `setMinDate()` does not update the *"To"* datepicker.

Any help on that?
I hope I've made myself clear

Comment: Under Android 5.0 a `DatePicker` will not call the `OnDateChanged()` method when it's in its default `CalendarView` mode, but it will do so if it's `Spinners` mode.     http://stackoverflow.com/a/27404483/5216567

Comment: I am on android 5.1.1. `OnDateChanged()` works (it gets fired every time I change the spinners) and my datepickers are on `Spinners` mode. My problem is on `setMinDate()`.